# scala - uninitialized variable declaration

Tags: scala

I have a variable in one of my scala classes, whose value is only set for the first time upon calling a specific method. The method parameter value will be the initial value of the field. So I have this:

```
classX {
  private var value: Int= _
  private var initialised = false

  def f(param: Int) {
    if (!initialised){
      value = param
      initialised = true
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a more scala-like way to do this? Options seem a bit too cumbersome...

Comment: What is the purpose of the f() method? Is it called multiple times, but ignored after the first? What happens if 'value' is accessed before the first time f() is called?

Comment: What you're doing is essentially self-managing a weak implementation of Option. What do you not like about them?

Comment: Be aware that your class is not thread-safe at all!

Comment: If you need vars, you might want to rethink your design. Can you explain more why do you have this requirement?

Answer (score 14):

Actually using `Option` is less cumbersome since the question of whether or not `value` has been initialized can be inferred from the value of the `Some` or `None` in the `Option`. This is more idiomatic Scala than using flags too.

```
class X() {
  var value: Option[Int] = None

  def f(param: Int) {
    value match{
      case None => value = Some(param)
      case Some(s) => println("Value already initialized with: " + s)
    }
  }
}

scala> val x = new X
x: X = X@6185167b

scala> x.f(0)

scala> x.value
res1: Option[Int] = Some(0)

scala> x.f(0)
Value already initialized with: 0
```

Comment: +1 learn `Option`. It is idiomatic and will keep you out of trouble. Also, I know you say `value` is set later, but strongly consider setting `value` in the class's constructor, a big step toward making the class immutable.

Comment: Can we do such stuff using a val?